# WPF Scrollviewer scroll to child element not working

Tags: wpf, scroll, scrollviewer, children

Here is what I am trying to do. I have a Scrollviewer and nested inside it are UserControls, nested in other UserControls, inside grids, stackpanels and other containers. When I click a button that adds yet another child somewhere within this hierarchy I would like to scroll to see said child. Code of function below:

```
 public static void ScrollParentNamedScrollViewerDown(DependencyObject child, string strTargetParent, DependencyObject newStartPoint = null)            
    {
        if(child == null) return;
        if(newStartPoint == null) newStartPoint = child;
        ScrollViewer scvPotentialTarget = GetParentOfType<ScrollViewer>(newStartPoint);
        if (scvPotentialTarget == null) return;
        if (scvPotentialTarget.Name != strTargetParent)
        {
            ScrollParentNamedScrollViewerDown(child, strTargetParent, scvPotentialTarget);
        }
        else
        {
            UIElement scrollTarget = child as UIElement;
            if (scrollTarget == null)
                scvPotentialTarget.ScrollToBottom();
            else{
                Point pTarget = scrollTarget.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), scvPotentialTarget);                    
                if (pTarget == null)
                    scvPotentialTarget.ScrollToBottom();
                else
                    scvPotentialTarget.ScrollToVerticalOffset(pTarget.Y);
            }
        }
```

This function is used like this:

```
gbSubWindow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
gbSubWindow.Content = uc;
ScrollParentNamedScrollViewerDown(gbSubWindow, "OmsWindowScrollViewer");
```

where gbSubWindow was a previously empty, hidden expander at the bottom of a nested UserControl

For some reason I am getting ridiculously low values for the vertical offset when I execute the TranslatePoint function - my scrollviewer scrollheight is near 800, and I am adding a child that will show up at the very bottom beneath 2 large child control and I am getting values in 160ish range.

Anyone have any ideas, what is happening here?

Comment: BringIntoView on the control

Comment: was not aware of this function. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case that is the answer

BringIntoView on the control
Since UserControl derives from FrameWorkElelement it should work.
I have only used it for ListItem

[FrameworkElement.BringIntoView Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598110%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Marked as answer because apparently I was again trying to reinvent the wheel.

That said, if anyone is looking at it and can tell my why I would be getting incorrect values from TranslatePoint, I am still curious.